# javascript onclick not working for android app

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

I'm trying to develop an android app using eclipse and phonegap. The app is a basic lighting calculator using javascript. I'm trying to call to the javascript function in the head of the document with an onclick to calculate the result. I believe the problem may be in the onclick=, onblur=, or onfocus=. My project is time sensitive any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my code and here is a link to a stand alone page showing the code working. http://www.everlastlight.com/energy_calc.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title>EverLast&reg; Lighting</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="../../css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../_assets/css/jqm-docs.css"/>
<!--<script src="../../js/calc.js"></script>-->
<script src="../../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../docs/_assets/js/jqm-docs.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="../../docs/_assets/js/calc1.js">-->
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function Calculate1()
{
            var no_fixtures1, hrs_yr1, cost_kwh1, watts1_1, watts2_1, invst1;
            var s_perfix$1, s_sitecost1_1, s_sitecost2_1, s_sav_yr1, s_recoup1, s_res1, s_res2_1;

                                            no_fixtures1 = document.basicecalc.no_fixtures1.value;
                                            hrs_yr1 = document.basicecalc.hrs_yr1.value;
                                            cost_kwh1 = document.basicecalc.cost_kwh1.value;
                                            watts1_1 = document.basicecalc.watts1_1.value;
                                            watts2_1 = document.basicecalc.watts2_1.value;
                                            invst1 = document.basicecalc.invst1.value;

                                            if ( watts1_1 == "" )
                                                            {alert("Please enter the wattage of the existing fixture");
                                                                            return;}

                                            //if ( watts2_1 == "" )
      //                  {alert("Please enter the wattage of the proposed fixture");
                                                                            //return;}
                                           else if ( no_fixtures1 == "" )
                            {alert("Please enter the number of fixtures at the site");
                            return;  }
         else{
                                                            s_perfix$1 = Math.round((watts1_1 - watts2_1)*(hrs_yr1)*(cost_kwh1)/10)/100;
                                                            s_sitecost1_1 = Math.round((watts1_1)*(hrs_yr1)*(no_fixtures1)*(cost_kwh1)/10)/100;
                                                            s_sitecost2_1 = Math.round((watts2_1)*(hrs_yr1)*(no_fixtures1)*(cost_kwh1)/10)/100;
                                                            s_sav_yr1 = Math.round((s_sitecost1_1-s_sitecost2_1)*100)/100;

                                                            s_res1 =(invst1/s_perfix$1)


                                                                            document.basicecalc.s_perfix$1.value   = "$"+ s_perfix$1;
                                                                            document.basicecalc.s_sitecost1_1.value = "$"+ s_sitecost1_1;
                                                                            document.basicecalc.s_sitecost2_1.value = "$"+ s_sitecost2_1;
                                                                            document.basicecalc.s_sav_yr1.value = "$"+ s_sav_yr1;


                                                                            if(invst1 !=="")
                                                                            {document.basicecalc.s_recoup1.value = Math.round(s_res1*12) + " months ("+ Math.round(s_res1*100)/100 + " yr.)";
                                                                            }

                                                            }

}

function MM_callJS(jsStr) { //v2.0
return eval(jsStr)
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v3.0
var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document); return x;
}

function MM_validateForm() { //v3.0
var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) { test=args[i+2]; val=MM_findObj(args[i]);
if (val) { nm=val.name; if ((val=val.value)!="") {
  if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1) { p=val.indexOf('@');
    if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
  } else if (test!='R') { num = parseFloat(val);
    if (val!=''+num) errors+='Please use only numbers.';
    if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) { p=test.indexOf(':');
      min=test.substring(8,p); max=test.substring(p+1);
      if (num<min || max<num) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
} } } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n'; }
} if (errors) alert(errors);
document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
}
</script>   
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" class="type-interior">

<div data-role="header" data-theme="f">
    <h1>EverLast&reg;</h1>
    <a href="../../" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
    <a href="../nav.html" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="fade">Search</a>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">

    <div class="content-primary">

    <h2>Basic Energy Calculator</h2>

    <p>
<div style="padding-right:0px;">
<p>Calculate energy savings by relamping your lighting system.<br>Also calculate the return on investment of the new system.<br><br>Fill in all the fields and click "calculate".<br><b>Your results will display below.</b></p>
</div>
<!--/body head :: Head Type B Ended -->



<!-- main body -->


<form name="basicecalc">


<!-- table 1 (user inputs) -->
<div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><span class="orange">*</span> Required<br> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span class="orange">*</span> Quantity of fixtures:  </td>
<td> </td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-align:right" name="no_fixtures1" maxlength="6" size="6" value="1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span class="orange">*</span> Average operating hours per year:  </td>
<td> </td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-align:right" name="hrs_yr1" maxlength="6" size="6" value="4500"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span class="orange">*</span> Cost per kilowatt hour:  </td>
<td>$</td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-align:right" name="cost_kwh1" maxlength="6" size="6" value="0.10"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span class="orange">*</span> Watts (per fixture) used in existing system:  </td>
<td> </td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-align:right" name="watts1_1" maxlength="6" size="6" onblur="MM_validateForm('watts1_1','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span class="orange">*</span> Watts (per fixture) used in new system:  </td>
<td> </td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-align:right" name="watts2_1" maxlength="6" size="6"   onblur="MM_validateForm('watts2_1','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><span class="orange">*</span>Cost to upgrade each fixture:  </td>
<td>$</td>
<td><input type="text" style="text-align:right" name="invst1" maxlength="6" size="6" onblur="MM_validateForm('invst1','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"> </td>
<td align="right"> <input name="calcbtn" type="button" class="calcbtn" title="Calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="Calculate1()">
</td>
</tr>

</table>
<a href="javascript:MM_callJS('Calculate1()');" data-role="button">Calculate</a>
</div>
<!-- / table 1 (user inputs) -->
<hr>
<br>
<div class="resultsLabel">Results</div>



<!-- table 2 (results) -->
<div class="resultsBlock">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<br>
<div><b>Cost of Electricity:</b></div>
    <!-- table 2a -->
    <div>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td>Current system:  </td>
    <td align="right"><input type="text" style="text-align:right" class="result" name="s_sitecost1_1" maxlength="8" readOnly onfocus="this.blur()" size="8">           </td>
    <td>&nbsp;/yr.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Proposed system:</td>

    <td align="right"><input type="text" style="text-align:right" class="result" name="s_sitecost2_1" maxlength="8" readOnly onfocus="this.blur()" size="8" onblur="MM_validateForm('s_sitecost2_1','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;/yr.</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <!-- / table 2a -->
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<div><b>Energy Savings (with proposed system)</b></div>

    <!-- table 2b -->
    <div>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td>Each fixture:</td>
    <td align="right"><input type="text" style="text-align:right" class="result" name="s_perfix$1" maxlength="8" readOnly onfocus="this.blur()" size="8">      </td>
    <td>&nbsp;/yr.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Total:</td>
    <td align="right"><input type="text" style="text-align:right" class="result" name="s_sav_yr1" maxlength="10" readOnly onfocus="this.blur()" size="8">   </td>
    <td>&nbsp;/yr.</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:12px;">* This cost should include the lamp, ballast, and labor required to replace the fixture. You may want to subtract any costs that would have been incurred with the current system.</div>
</tr>

</table>        

    </p>


    </div><!--/content-primary -->      

    <div class="content-secondary">

        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d">

                <h3>More in this section</h3>

                <ul data-role="listview"  data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li>
            <li><a href="watts.html">Watts Per Sq. Ft.</a></li>
            <li><a href="lightinglayout.html">Lighting Layout</a></li>
            <li><a href="fixreplace.html">Fixture Replacement</a></li>
            <li><a href="dimming.html">Dimming Watts</a></li>
            <li><a href="costwait.html">Cost of Waiting</a></li>
            <li><a href="samplelife.html">Simple Life Cycle</a></li>

                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>      

</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" class="footer-docs" data-theme="c" align="center">
        <p>&copy; 2012 EverLast&reg;. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This java script call might have problem with phonegap jquery mobile android applications. You are doing like a pure html javascript call.

In phonegap-jquery mobile, before loading any script, you have to check the deviceready in phonegap method.

Just go through the below sample,

After including all the libraries (jquery mobile js, css and phonegap js), open a script and add the below code,

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     function onLoad(){

          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);

     }
function onDeviceReady(){
/*use selectors to trigger a event*/
/*here you can call the javascript events with jquery live method*/
}
      </script>
```

This format help you